# Translate a postgresql search query to_tsquery to use criteriaBuilder

Tags: spring, postgresql, kotlin, jpa, jsonb

I want to take this query using full text search in postgresql and be able to write it in spring boot using the CriteriaBuilder but without the native query using jpa functions

`SELECT * FROM search_data WHERE search @@ to_tsquery('parameters');`

^^
Its works correctly in postgresqsl but in application i cannot fix it.

```
CREATE TABLE search_data
(
    id              UUID         NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    data           JSONB        NOT NULL,
);

ALTER TABLE search_data ADD search tsvector GENERATED ALWAYS AS
    (to_tsvector('simple', data)) STORED;

CREATE INDEX search_idx ON search_data USING GIN(search);
```

How to do it in code?

I registered new sqlfunction:

```
@Service
class CustomSearchBuilderContributor : MetadataBuilderContributor {
    override fun contribute(metadataBuilder: MetadataBuilder) {
        metadataBuilder.applySqlFunction(
            "fts", SQLFunctionTemplate(BooleanType.INSTANCE, "@@ plainto_tsquery(?1)")
        )
    }
}
```

and in specification:

```
val searchQuery = "search parameters"
val predicates = mutableListOf<Predicate>()
predicates.add(cb.equal(cb.function("fts",Boolean::class.java, root.get<String>("search"), cb.literal(searchQuery)), true))
cb.and(*predicates.toTypedArray())
```

When I started application and invoke this code i get errror:

```
ERROR: function fts(tsvector, character varying) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 476
```